Spring boot 3.x version not able to clear the stale connections, giving error"org.postgressql.util.PSQLException :This connection has been closed"
Currently I have developed a microservice using the latest spring boot version ( 3.2.4/3.3 ) with JDK 21 which is connecting to the database ( PostGreSQL ) and used JPA Repository to run the prepared statement to fetch data from the database without having hibernate 2nd level caching enabled. Currently I am facing an issue, in case of database restart the microservice is not able to fetch the data from the database because the latest version of the JPA framework is not able to handle the stale connections which is not available due to database service restart.
Its holding the stale connection and trying with stale connection only. This issue was not present in the spring boot version 2.x. Also during troubleshooting I could see the error occurred if you use any other connection pool like hikariCP, pgbouncer. If you are using the centralized connection pool like pgbouncer then in case of pgbouncer restart also having the similar connection issue. The issue solved when we restart the microservice.
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper :: SQL Error: 0, SQLState:08003 o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper :: The Connection has been closed.. org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException : could not prepare statement [ This connection has been closed ] [ select emp_id,emp_name,emp_address from Employee where emp_id = ?] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException ( HibernateJpaDialect.java: 274 ) 

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java: 241 ) 

at . . 

Caused by : org.hibernate.exception.JDBCException : could not prepare statement [ This connection has been closed ] [ select emp_id,emp_name,emp_address from Employee where emp_id = ?] Caused by : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException : This connection has been closed. 

at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed (PgConnection.java: 1009 ) 
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.preparedStatement (PgConnection.java: 1859 ) 
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.preparedStatement (PgConnection.java: 534 ) 
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPrepareImpl$5.doPrepare( StatementPreparerImpl.java:152 ) 
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPrepareImpl$5StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement( StatementPreparerImpl.java:183 )

